# Routing rails url contains multiple parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am doing a sharing application like facebook ,where user can share a url on their posts 
I have a user posts form and I populate the form from url params 
the problem I want to route /sharer?urlparams to the sharer action on my controller without removing the url params in the url 
somthing like

localhost:3000/sharer?params[:url]="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"&params[:title]=""&params[:description]=""

N.B update 
I found these method

```
  match'/sharer/:url'=>"manys#sharer",:constraints => {:url => /.*/}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want these url to route to sharer action on my posts controller without changing in the url after routing

Answer (score 0):

If the url and controller name are not equal best way is the following method.

```
match "/sharer/:id/share" => redirect{ |params, request| "/posts/#{params[:id]}/share?#{request.query_string}" }
```

If the url name and the action name is same you can use something like this.

```
resources :sharer do
 member do
  get :share
 end
end
```

You can use collection instead of member routing according to your url. I used member because my example is taking id in the url path. Therefore it becomes a member route.